# Finding 2-Tuple Combinations of IEnumerable<T> collection, C#

Tags: c#, collections, combinations, combinatorics

I would like to implement a method, that takes a collection of an unknown Type as a parameter and returns a Collection of 2-tuples which contains all possible distinct combinations  from these elements (with no repetition). My Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Get2Combinations<T>(this 
IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        /*foreach (var item1 in col)
        {
            col.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
            foreach (var item2 in col)
            {
                yield return new Tuple<T, T>(item1, item2);
            }
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < col.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < col.Count(); j++)
            {
                yield return new Tuple<T, T>(col.ElementAt(i), 
col.ElementAt(j));
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm doing is i take the first element and take a pair with every other. Then using this inner for loop i loop through all the remaining ones. The problem i see is the method col.ElementAt(i). If we look into source code, we see that if 'col' is of type IList, then this gets directly the value at given index, but taking any other collection, this would be veery very slow and would take a lot of time. 
I attempted to deal with this using foreach loops (the commented section), which are efficient when using IEnumerable, but that part just doesn't work, because the enumerator is common for both inner and outer loop and therefore this produces set of all 2-tuples, where some of them are repeated.
Would anyone give me some suggestions, how to improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Enumerable is designed to describe a class where you can iterate through it (like a stream). Its not intended to support efficiently random access (like an array).

Where you use Count() you are forcing the Enumerable to iterate itself to its end, so in the case of a Stream this will wait until the entire stream is read. Of course a Stream might not support efficient direct access, or even buffer its content in memory (remember - it just promises to support enumeration) - so subsequently calling ElementAt() could force it to re-read from the beginning to the position indicated.

Best way to solve this is to swap from IEnumerable to IList. This means it does support random access; clearly it could still be poorly performing, but thats not the responsibility of your function.

Comment: Another point: ``IEnumerable<T> col`` could be infinite, then the whole concept falls down…

Comment: A good point - IEnumerable<T> only requires implementation of GetEnumerator(). The Count() method is an extension method not part of the interface, that in the circumstance of an infinite collection, would (presumably) hang.

Comment: I checked the reference source: it will throw if the counter overflows. Still, likely a while to wait for that…